# Why would I need explicit declaration of REST resources in Application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

In several recent examples of providing JAX-RS services in a microservice-style architecture, I saw something like this when defining the root resource:

```
 @Override
 public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
    resources.add(my.package.MyService.class);
    return resources;
 }
```

Why would I need to override this method and explicitely declare my resources instead of just let them discover by their `@Path` annotation?

Comment: Since I got an "unclear" close voting, I try to clarify: One can let JAX-RS implementation scan for all resources, then the Application class would just be empty or one can override the getClasses() method in Application and list all resources manually. I like to know, what the 2nd method is for (since one can find many usages of it)? It seems unnecessary, so maybe someone can give me an explanation in which cases this method should be used instead of auto-discovery.

Comment: [When to Use JAX-RS Class-path Scanning Mechanism](https://blogs.oracle.com/japod/when-to-use-jax-rs-class-path-scanning-mechanism)

Comment: @PaulSamsotha: Interesting information, haven't thought about that

Comment: Also consider third-party features life filters that aren't annotated. Once you register one manually, you need to register all manually, since registering even one disables the classpath scanning.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you run into old or not very qualified examples. At least with JAX-RS 2.x there is no need to do it. You do not even need to register JAX-RS in your web.xml.
 Simply add JAX-RS activator - class annotation with `@ApplicationPath("/your/rest/root")` that extends `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`.
After that your JAX-RS provider should scan all resources annotated with `@Path` and register them automatically. The same is true for all interceptors and providers.
For more examples head over to official [repo with Java EE samples](https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples) or [official samples for Wildfly app server](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart) - you might need to change branch based on the JEE version you use.

Hope that helps and happy hacking.

Comment: Thanks for the info - yes, I know that about the activator, I was only curious when one would specify it explicitely, but Paul mentioned something interesting above.